# How do I read from STDIN in Rakudo Perl6?

Tags: io, stdin, raku, rakudo

As simple as that, **how can I read input from STDIN in Perl6?**

I reckon there's many ways of doing it, but I'm interested in the most idiomatic Perl6 solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard input file descriptor in Perl6 is `$*IN` (in Perl5 the `*STDIN` typeglob had a reference to the STDIN file descriptor as `*STDIN{IO}`).

One way of reading from standard input is the following:

```
for lines() {
    say "Read: ", $_
}
```

In fact, `lines()` without an invocant object defaults to `$*IN.lines()`.

An alternative that uses a local variable is:

```
for $*IN.lines() -> $line {
    say "Read: ", $line
}
```

Would be cool to see more alternative ways of doing it.

Comment: Sure. `slurp()` without arguments slurps your `$*IN`.

Comment: Tehcnically speaking, `*STDIN` is a typeglob not a file descriptor. The I/O handle(s) associated with that typeglob is `*STDIN{IO}`.  The file descriptor number of the filehandle  component of that I/O handle filehandle–dirhandle pair is `fileno(*STDIN{IO})`.

Comment: @GlitchMr: why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @cosimo Add please also reading by blocks and/or different separator – analogy of [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) variable.

Answer (score 10):

You can also slurp entire standard input using `slurp` without arguments. This code will slurp entire input and print it.

```
print slurp;
```

If you want to get lines, you can use `lines()` iterator, working like `<>` in Perl 5. Please note that unlike Perl 5, it automatically chomps the line.

```
for lines() {
    say $_;
}
```

When you want to get single line, instead of using `lines()` iterator, you can use `get`.

```
say get();
```

If you need to ask user about something, use `prompt()`.

```
my $name = prompt "Who are you? ";
say "Hi, $name.";
```